# Sync content from contentful dynamically

Tags: gatsby, contentful

We have a requirement of 100+ sites, every site will have its own blog. Any change(CRUD) in blog should reflect in the site. 
There might be a widget which is pulling data from server instead of cache.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Contentful's sync endpoint. It allows you to fetch delta updates which means that you don't have to fetch all the data everytime. :)

https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/sync/